# Capitalizing all words in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im needing help making all emails in a google sheets capitalized in the column. When I try it deletes them all.
can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Function Upper

```
=UPPER(Cell_Reference)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your values are in column A use this in column B row 1:

```
=INDEX(UPPER(A:A))
```

also you can use proper to get capital for each word:

```
=INDEX(PROPER(A:A))
```